# Create rotate animation without stop point

Tags: android

I want rotate animation working without stop point

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="25000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="-360" />
</set>
```

from 0 to -360 and animation stop 1 second and rotate again but I want working without stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
objectAnimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgCircle1, View.ROTATION, 0f, 360f).setDuration(4000);
objectAnimator1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
objectAnimator1.setDuration(2500);
objectAnimator1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```